# chosen not update after select option changes by jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a hidden(display:none) select option, according to it chosen created,

```
    <div>
        <select class="fpd-elements-dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <option value="none">None</option>
        <option value="1406378948898">Base</option><option value="1406378949108">Shadow</option></select>
        <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single fpd-border-color" style="width: 100%;" title="">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single"><span>None</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I want change (select one element(Base) by default) 
I try below jquery code

```
//$(' .fpd-elements-dropdown').show();
 $('.fpd-elements-dropdown option:contains(Base)').prop('selected','selected');
//$('.fpd-elements-dropdown').val($('.fpd-elements-dropdown option:contains(Base)').val());  
$('.chosen-container-single').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

select option changed but chosen not changed 
also I try

```
$('.chosen-container-single').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

but chosen selected Item not changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my mistakes

```
$('.fpd-elements-dropdown option:contains(Base)').prop('selected','selected');
$('.chosen-container-single').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I should `trigger('chosen:updated')` on `.fpd-elements-dropdown` instead `.chosen-container-single.

So

```
$('.fpd-elements-dropdown option:contains(Base)').prop('selected','selected');
$('.fpd-elements-dropdown').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

work correctly

Comment: @RederickDeathwill you're welcome ;) I will be happy when my answer save others time ;)